# Can I run multiple node version on Jenkins?

Tags: node.js, angular, jenkins

Currently I met one problem about Jenkins.

The ex-projects are using Angular 4 with node version 8.

The new project is using Angular 8 with node version 12.

Is there any way to config multiple node version on Jenkins?

Answer (score 4):

THe [NodeJS plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/NodeJS+Plugin) should allow you to declare multiple NodeJS installation in the global settings

[image: https://wiki.jenkins.io/download/attachments/46334885/image2018-3-31%2016%3A40%3A29.png?version=1&modificationDate=1522507231000&api=v2]

Answer (score 3):

I recommend you to install **nvm** by default on your agents and edit the version you want to use by a simple command :

```
nvm use 12.4
```

**Why?**
Because installing a Jenkins plugin requires maintenance and I personally ended up with the above solution because it's **more flexible** and you have **more control**.

[How to install nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm)

Comment: Yes I prefer this one but I am using windown and NVM is working only on Mac.

Comment: There is a NVM Windows Version out there: https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows. Works like a charm for us.

Comment: Is your Jenkins installed on windows? o_O

Answer (score 0):

You can use Nvm Wrapper Plugin to manage Node version with diff projects.
https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Nvm+Wrapper+Plugin